# Get preview of references and footnotes when hover in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

It looks like this ebook is done with `bookdown`:

https://mixtape.scunning.com/

When hovering over a reference or footnote, the information is displayed already:

[image]

What is the name of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current online version of [**`Causal Inference: The Mixtape`**](https://mixtape.scunning.com/) is actually done using [Quarto](https://quarto.org), not `{bookdown}`. And AFAIK, it seems Quarto makes use of [`Tippy.js`](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) to show footnotes on hover.

However, [`bookdown::bs4_book()`](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/bookdown/reference/bs4_book.html) has similar functionality. It has an argument `footnotes_inline` which is by-default `TRUE`.

> `footnotes_inline`: By default, footnotes will be set inline and shown on hover. Set to `FALSE` to keep footnotes at the bottom of the page with links.

As an example of `bookdown::bs4_book`, checkout the footnote used [in this section of **`Mastering Shiny`** book](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-ui.html#free-text)

Comment: Any chance I can implement something similar in `gitbook`?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this in the case of gitbook.